# Order statistic of i.i.d exponential($\lambda$) random variables, $X_{(n, k_n)}$ convergence in probability

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence, order-statistics, exponential-distribution

Suppose that $X_1,X_2$,....are iid from exponential($\lambda$).For n $\geq$ 1, let $X_{(n,1)}\le X_{(n,2)}\le X_{(n,3)}\le.......\le X_{(n,n)}$ be the order statistics of $X_1,X_2....X_n$. Suppose that $k_n$ is a sequence of integers satisfying $1\le k_n \le n$ for all n, and 
            
  
  ${\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{k_n}{n}} = p\in(0,1)$

Show that as n$\to\infty$

$\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\mathit{{X_{(n, k_n)}\to-\frac{1}{\lambda}\log(1-p)}}$

 I am thankful for any help.

Comment: Why the crazy encoding?

Comment: was my first time thats why

Answer (score 1):

Fix $\epsilon > 0$.

Let $Y_1 \sim \text{Binom}(n, (1-p) e^{\lambda \epsilon})$
and $Y_2 \sim \text{Binom}(n, (1-p) e^{-\lambda \epsilon})$.
\begin{align}
P(|X_{n,k_n} + \log(1-p)/\lambda| > \epsilon)
&\le P(X_{n,k_n} < - \log(1-p)/\lambda - \epsilon)
+ P(X_{n,k_n} > - \log(1-p)/\lambda + \epsilon)
\\
&= P(\text{less than $n-k_n$ of the $X_i$ are $\ge - \log(1-p)/\lambda - \epsilon$})
+ P(\text{more than $n-k_n$ of the $X_i$ are $\ge - \log(1-p)/\lambda + \epsilon$})
\\
&= P(Y_1 < n-k_n) + P(Y_2 > n-k_n)
\\
&= P(Y_1/n < 1 - k_n/n) + P(Y_2/n > 1 - k_n/n).
\end{align}
By the law of large numbers, $Y_1/n \to (1-p) e^{\lambda \epsilon} > 1 - p$ in probability, so the first term will tend to zero. Similarly, the second term will tend to zero.